# How to match all inside asteriks without spaces between them

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to match all strings between 2 asterisks without spaces at the start or at the end, also I don't want to match only asterisks text.

For example:

```
* text* //don't match
******** //don't match
*text * //don't match
* text * //don't match
*  text* //don't match
*text* //match
*Hello World !* //match
```

I have tried:

```
(?<=\*)(?!\s)(.*?)(?!\s)(?=\*)
```

But it's only working on the space in the start, as you can see: https://regex101.com/r/Hpe0br/3/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of negative lookarounds, try using negated character sets instead: `[^\s*]` will match any character which isn't a space character or an asterisk. Add it to the beginning and end, just between the lookbehind and lookahead. Also, you probably don't want `(.*?)`, because the `.` will also undesirably match `*`s:

```
(?<=\*)[^\s*](?:[^*]+[^\s*])?(?=\*)
```

https://regex101.com/r/Hpe0br/6

The inner group `(?:[^*]+[^\s*])?` is optional to allow for single-character matches, like `*a*`.

Also note that if you're using Javascript, lookbehind is a pretty new feature - no older browser supports it, and it's not transpilable. You might consider *matching* the `*`s and capturing the text between the `*`s in group instead:

```
\*([^\s*](?:[^*]+[^\s*])?)\*
```

The substring you want will be in the first captured group.

https://regex101.com/r/Hpe0br/7

Comment: It is possible to match asterisks inside asterisks if they have space between them?
like: `*t * t*` .

Comment: Instead of repeating `[^*]`, repeat a group that alternates between ` * ` (asterisk surrounded by spaces) and `[^*]`. https://regex101.com/r/Hpe0br/8